# How to have a sorted set of objects based on a specific field?

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting

I need to retrieve a sorted list of objects based on their `sort field`; Their collection type is `SortedSet` but the code throws following exception.
I also tried to add `@Sort` annotation as explained in sorted collection section of [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html) but it seems like it is deprecated!

**Exception**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A sorted collection must define and ordering or sorting
```

**Code**

```
SortedSet<Offer> offers = new TreeSet<Offer>();
```

**Classes**

```
public class Person {
 @Id
 long id;
 @OneToMany 
 //@OrderBy("sort ASC") <<< If I use this just one offer will be in the collection 
 SortedSet<Offer> offers = new TreeSet<Offer>();
 ...
}

public class Offer implements Comparable<Offer>{

 @Id
 long id;
 String name;
 short sort;
 @Override
 public int compareTo(Offer o) {
    return sort - o.sort;
 }
}
```

Comment: On which bases are you trying to sort? It seems you are trying to sort a class not an Integer or String??

Comment: I don't use Hibernate, but the javadocs that note it as deprecated have a comment, "Use [SortComparator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/SortComparator.html) or [SortNatural](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/SortNatural.html) instead depending on need." Sounds like your need is for the SortComparator.

Comment: I need to sort Offer objects of offers collection based on values their sort fields.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to specify the column name to be put in the ORDER BY clause

try to add this annotation to the SortedSet

```
@javax.persistence.OrderBy("sort")
```

If you need ordering by more than one column, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42085686/5772882).