# JPA/Hibernate @OrderBy annotation with multiple columns and ASC/DESC for each

Tags: jpa, hibernate-annotations, jpa-annotations

I would like to sort a OneToMany field with the @OrderBy annotation with multiple columns and specify the sort order for each but I can't seem to find the info anywhere on whether how to or if it's impossible.
The specs for the annotation says:

```
orderby_list::= orderby_item [,orderby_item]*
orderby_item::= property_or_field_name [ASC | DESC]
```

so my guess is it's not possible but I prefer to ask anyway.

Putting the following throws a HibernateException on deployment :

```
@OrderBy("field1 DESC, field2 DESC, field3 DESC, field4 DESC")
```

Generating :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to parse order-by fragment
```

Thanks

Comment: are "column1", "column2" etc columns ? or FIELDS?

Comment: Sorry, field names

Comment: ok, so your JPA provider has an issue based on the info presented here and you should raise an issue on them

Comment: ok, checking further into it. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you have a class `Person` with 2 fields, `firstName` and `lastName` then with a query you can do

```
SELECT p FROM Person p ORDER BY p.firstName ASC, p.lastName DESC
```

which is what the JPQL BNF says.

In terms of when you have a List of `Person` objects, you can define the List ordering like this (same syntax)

```
@OneToMany
@OrderBy("firstName ASC, lastName DESC")
List<Person> myList;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not talking about a query but specifically about the annotation. I want the collection in the OneToMany sorted when it is fetched.

Comment: I have tried that and I have a parse error when I deploy the application : "org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to parse order-by fragment". I'll update my post.

Comment: Well that is what the JPA spec defines, and what the JPA provider I use accepts, so suggest that you raise an issue on your JPA provider

Comment: Turns out the problem was caused by the antlr dependency which I had to exclude. I accepted your answer anyway as I was hunting around for the confirmation that the syntax was indeed correct.